# google action project not showing on google home

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant

I want test 'Account Linking' but not showing my project id (ex. `[test]exampleProject`) on google home app -> Home Control section

First, i set like this:

[image]

google home login id is same to action google project id.

already i saw this issue page ( https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/1 )

but i don't now that how they solved this problem.

i need help, please.

Answer (score 1):

i solve it...

In order to be visible in the home control section of the Google home app, you must build it to smart home the first time you set up Google Action.